# node.js module for specific block of code

Tags: node.js

I have a specific block of code (the forEach loop) that I use all over the place in my code base, whenever I have an "item".

How can I refactor this into a module or a global function that I can call whenever I need to.

Here's the context:

```
Item.findById(itemid).populate('wants').exec(function(err, item){
        item.wants.forEach(function(person){
            person.avatar = gravatar.url(person.email, {size: 80, default: 'mm' });
        });

       //do some more stuff with item
});
```

I want to re-use this forEach loop in other places where I have an "item" object. I'm thinking I pass in the item object and return it again.

```
    item.wants.forEach(function(person){
        person.avatar = gravatar.url(person.email, {size: 80, default: 'mm' });
    });
```

Something like:

```
var myLib = require('./lib/myLib');
...
item = myLib.doStuff( item );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `./lib/myLib.js` file would look like this:

```
module.exports.doStuff = function(item) {
    item.wants.forEach(function(person){
        person.avatar = gravatar.url(person.email, {size: 80, default: 'mm' });
    });
    return item;
}
```

You can then require and use like you outlined already:

```
var myLib = require('./lib/myLib');
item = myLib.doStuff( item );
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this, but because it's a mongoose object, there's something special about not being allowed to override it. The re-assignment causes other properties to disappear `item = myLib.doStuff( item );` I got around it by just doing: `myLib.doStuff(item)` -- I guess everything is a reference and not a copy. Not exactly sure why this works, but it does.